# Monitoring Kubernetes CronJob & Job in Grafana for today day only

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, grafana

I'm trying to create a Dashboard in Grafana that will show the status of Cronjob & Job success & fail.

Currently i'm using `kube_job_status_succeeded` to get a status job, but the issue here PromQL also take a 3 days of job status back, but i only wanted for 1 days job status.

I try to be creative with `kube_job_created` but no luck.

How can i get only `kube_job_status_succeeded` for 1 day only ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. I found no straightforward solution, bur eventually I solved it with a workaround.

The problem is that `kube_job_status_succeeded` will always present number of rows equal to `.spec.successfulJobsHistoryLimit` (if some jobs in the past have succeded) with value of 1, and number of rows equal to `.spec.failedJobsHistoryLimit` (if some jobs in the past have failed) with value of 0. Moreover, `kube_job_status_succeeded` does not tell you when the job was performed.

In other words, `kube_job_status_succeeded` just store `.spec.successfulJobsHistoryLimit` (default: 3) of most recent succesful jobs and `.spec.failedJobsHistoryLimit` (default: 1) of most recent failed jobs

My workaround is based on joining data from kube_job_status_succeeded and kube_job_created. In this way, I take most recent timestamp of successful job. Then  I deduct it from current timestamp. In result I get a info how long ago last successful job execution took a place.

```
time() - max(kube_job_status_succeeded{namespace="my_namespace",job_name=~"job_name.*"} * on (job_name) kube_job_created{namespace="my_namespace",job_name=~"job_name.*"})
```

In Grafana it looks like this:

[image]

Maybe this is not direct answer to your question, but I believe that this might be a good starting point to achieve your goal. In Grafana you can do some data mapping to present time diff calculated in the query as one big "success"/"failed" label, depending on your neads

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the `.spec.successfulJobsHistoryLimit` to 1 instead of the default value of 3?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#jobs-history-limits